# Apache Phoenix - GCP Data Proc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hbase, google-cloud-dataproc, apache-phoenix, dataproc

I am doing a POC on Google Cloud Dataproc along with HBase as one of the component.

I created cluster and was able to get the cluster running along with the HBase service. I can list and create tables via shell.

I want to use the Apache Phoenix as the client to query on HBase. I installed that on the cluster by referring to this [link](https://thecustomizewindows.com/2018/12/how-to-install-apache-phoenix-sql-on-hbase/).

The installation when fine but when I execute sqlline.py localhost which should create the Meta table in hbase. It actually fails and gives error as Region in Transistion.

Does anyone know how to resolve this or is there a limitation that Apache Phoenix cannot be used along with Dataproc.

Answer (score -1):

There is no limitation on Dataproc to use Apache Phoenix. You might want to dig deeper into the error message, it might be a configuration issue.